# Entity Framework Updating Entities error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting this a generic error:-

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'entity' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate

Its happening below on the line when the entity is trying to change its state.

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        if (entity.Id == default(int))
        {
            entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
            entity.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;

            Context.Initial.Add(initial);
        }
        else
        {
            entity.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;
            Context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting it when I

- Reload the context i.e. initializing the repository from the view.
- Using the attach properly instead `Context.T.Attach(entity)`

And when I dont change the state info or use attach, it doesnt update anything.

Here is my Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(NewViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      m_CTS.InsertOrUpdate(viewModel.entity);
      m_CTS.Save();

      // My big problem is that the Primary key that 
      // was generated doesnt come back from the view 
      // once edited, so I have created a property in 
      // the viewmodel to handle this

      viewModel.ID = viewModel.entity.Id;

      return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = viewModel.entity.Id });
    }
    else
    {
      return View("New", viewModel);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
  // Getting this from the same context of when it was created
  viewModel.entity = respoitory.Find(id);

  return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(NewViewModel viewModel)
{
   // Could be the problem : As I said above the ID on the entity.id 
   // never comes back from the view (because I am using a viewmodel?) 
   // So I need to assign the ViewModel ID to the entity model id 
   // before I try and update it

   viewModel.entity.Id = viewModel.ID;

   m_CTS.InsertOrUpdate(viewModel.entity);
   m_CTS.Save();

   return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = viewModel.entity.Id });
}
```

Is there a reason why I am getting this error with the above code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identified the problem within the comments of your code:

```
       // My big problem is that the Primary key that 
       // was generated doesnt come back from the view 
       // once edited, so I have created a property in the viewmodel to handle this
```

To fix this, add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` to your view. Now when you POST to the controller, your view model parameter will contain the Id field that you sent to the view in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the same error by the id does come back to the POST now thanks..

Comment: I don't understand the problem, then. Which controller method leads to the exception?

Comment: I found a solution, I used AsNoTracking() when I first retrieve the entity from the context, not sure if this is the absolute right solution, seems to be ok so far, when I finish testing, will post. cheers

Comment: If I induce your design correctly from your comment, the `DbContext` stays alive between web requests. Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I do not dispose of the context

Comment: I mean, does the `DbContext` object get destroyed with the rest of the AppDomain after fulfilling the web request, as would happen in a regular MVC application? Or are you doing something to extraordinary to make it last longer? ...

Comment: ... I ask because the error message is pretty clear on what the problem is. If you have the correct Id value, which you should have now, then the problem is that the same entity is already loaded within the context's memory cache. So it must be left over from a previous query. This normally isn't a problem because the intended usage is to create and dispose of a new context each time that a unit of work is performed.

Comment: Hi Keith I agree with that, as that entity is in my 'local' object too. but the error still happens, but with this AsNotracking method, it now seems to work. Not enitrely sure why!